# How can I do a 'StartsWith' search on each string of a single attribute using entity framework dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, search, dbcontext

Hey I'm trying to query my database using c# entity framework but I'm getting hung up on some logic.

For example, lets say that we are searching for a place name in a database and the name we are searching for is "shenandoah national park"

If I type in "nation" or "park" -- I want "shenandoah national park" to come up in my search results.

The code below will only match on the first string of a place name.

If I type in "nation" I will not get any results. Can somebody please help me with the logic, I'm not really familiar with the entity framework syntax. Thanks!

```
   Entities dbPOEntity = new Entities(); //Entities is an auto generated class that extends dbContext 

   List<Space> lsSpace = dbPOEntity.Spaces.Where(sp => sp.Name.StartsWith(word)).OrderBy(sp => sp.Name).ToList();
```

edit: For example only want results for --- she nat par (any or all)

Comment: Use `.Contains` instead of `.StartsWith`

Comment: I think you need to have it mapped as a SQL function

Comment: What is you typed `"andoah"`?  Would you want it to match `"shenandoah national park"`?

Comment: @DStanley no, we would only get results for she  nat  par (any or all)

Comment: I know this doesn't directly address the question, but it's not very effective to implement full text search in a database like this.  A purpose built search engine like ElasticSearch (Lucene) is much better suited to this.  I mention this  because I learned the lesson myself the hard way and wish somebody had given me this advice.  Another alternative would be to parse the text strings into tokens and store the individual tokens in a separate table. Perhaps I'm reading too much into your question and my advice doesn't apply.  If so, please carry on and forget you ever read this.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the case where the word is preceded by a space:

```
List<Space> lsSpace = dbPOEntity.Spaces
                                .Where(sp => sp.Name.StartsWith(word) 
                                          || sp.Name.Contains(" "+word)
                                .OrderBy(sp => sp.Name)
                                .ToList();
```

Note that the query will require a full table scan since you can't create an index that looks for an abritrary *substring*.  In index can be used if the string *starts with* a string, but not *contains*.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want it to *start with* the word, you want it to *contain* the word.

```
List<Space> lsSpace = dbPOEntity.Spaces
    .Where(sp => sp.Name.Contains(word))
    .OrderBy(sp => sp.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The issue with this if we do a search for a string like "con" -- we would get a results like "Wisconsin" and we wanted to avoid this for the business use. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Edited for your commit. try that.

```
Entities dbPOEntity = new Entities(); //Entities is an auto generated class that extends dbContext 

List<Space> lsSpace = dbPOEntity.Spaces
.Where(sp =>   sp.Name.Contains(word+" ")
             ||sp.Name.Contains(" "+word)).OrderBy(sp => sp.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: The issue with this if we do a search for a string like "con" -- we would get a results like "Wisconsin" and we wanted to avoid this for the business use. Thank you though

Comment: Can you give me an example of a search term that needs sp.Name.Contains(word+" ")? I'm not sure if I need that